# Using wildcards for Puppet Packages?

Tags: puppet

Is there way I can do this ?

> package { 'firmware': ensure   => $version-*, }

instead of specifying the entire version,

> package { 'firmware':
>           ensure   => $version-r20130530 }

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Ladadadada So I can switch versions when the package is built.
For example, if I have test server, $version = 1.2-test-r20130530
so when i build r20130606, i dont need to change again in the puppet manifest.

Comment: What package provider?  If Debian maybe make a meta package that you update to always depend on the version you want.

Comment: @Zoredache No its a custom gentoo package for our firmware.

Comment: ensure => latest should work, surely ?, or a hiera lookup / parameter lookup if you want to avoid touching the manifest file.

Comment: @Sirex The problem with ensure => latest is I have three different servers and want only one of them to run the latest version and the other two should run the specific version which is stable rather.

Comment: This is what hiera solves, have that one server have 'latest' and the others the specfic version, then do ensure => hiera('fireware_version')

Comment: @Sirex that would have been a good option, but will have to update puppet coz our systems are running an older version of puppet and hiera is supported on 2.7.x or later :(

Comment: yeah. you should really consider it, seriously. It's really, really useful. Particularly with hiera-gpg so you can store passwords without exposing them.

Comment: If you're using a sane package manager it sounds like you probably just want `ensure => latest`.